# How to find matching values between 2 excel sheets.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns A and B, in sheet X and 2 columns A and B in sheet Y, column A has a few different values but some are the same eg row 1=42 row 2=42 row 3=43.
I want to know if the value in Column B match's on both sheets against column A. is there a formula I can use to find this?

in column A each row is a number eg 42, 42, 42, 43, 43 then in column B there is a different number for each row eg 42-333, 42-345, 42-678, 43-999. so when I vlookup i would get the 1st number it finds next to 42 for every row that is 42 but I need to find all the different values that are next to 42

Comment: I have not fully understood your problem. Maybe it would help if you show more of your data. But I have the feeling that the [MATCH function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-HP005209168.aspx) and or [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) may help you.

Comment: vlookup works except it only gives me the first value it finds

Comment: in column A each row is a number eg 42, 42, 42, 43, 43 then in column B there is a different number for each row eg 42-333, 42-345, 42-678, 43-999. so when I vlookup i would get the 1st number it finds next to 42 for every row that is 42 but I need to find all the different values that are next to 42.

Comment: You can use MATCH to find all lines in the second sheet for which in column A there is a corresponding value on the first. BTW, you can edit your question to included additional information.

Comment: I suggest using an [array formula](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/05/13/vlookup-return-multiple-unique-distinct-values-in-excel/). The "recommended blog articles" also provide several similar examples. This will let you get all matches in a range from a `MATCH` or `VLOOKUP`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=IF(COLUMN()>COUNTIF(Y!$A:$A,$A1)+2,"",INDEX(Y!$B:$B,MATCH($A1,Y!$A$1:$A$10,0)+COLUMN()-3))
```

in C1 of sheet X copied across (say to ColumnI) and down to suit. Change the `Y`s to `X`s to use in C1 of sheet Y.

To help identify matches, put in J1 of each sheet `=IFERROR(MATCH(B1,C1:I1,0),"")` and copy down to suit.